# Using .find() on a variable in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have been banging my head against the desk for a while on this and I am hoping someone can help. Basically in this I have divs that when created are assigned a pair# class. I am trying to create an event that on drop checks the 3rd index item in the div inside the div the event occurs, and then checking to see if there is a match on the same item within the div of it's pair. Hopefully I can explain this within the comments. So here is what I have:

```js
console.log($(this)[0].classList[3])
// logs pair0 in this case, but could pull any of the pair#s, which is what I need.

var currentPair = $(this)[0].classList[3]
//sets to pair0
console.log(currentPair)

var pairDivs = currentPair.find("div")
//errors: currentPair.find is not a function

var pairDivs2 = $(currentPair).find("div")
//errors: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ".pair0" 

var currentPair2 = '\".' + $(this)[0].classList[3] + '\"'
// my attempt to make it the string ".pair0"
console.log(currentPair2)
// logs ".pair0"

var pairDivs3 = $(currentPair2).find("div")
//errors: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ".pair0"

var pairDivs4 = $('.pair0').find("div")
//manually putting in the pair, which no longer allows the content to be dynamic
console.log(pairDivs);
//brings up the divs needed


if (pairDivs4[0] != undefined && pairDivs4[1] != undefined) {
//makes sure both buckets have items in them
  if (pairDivs4[0].classList[4] == pairDivs4[1].classList[4]) {
  //compares 5 class of both divs inside the pair divs
    var newStatus = pairDivs4[1].classList[4] + 'Text'
  console.log(newStatus)
    //in this case logs strongText
  $('#currentStatus').addClass(newStatus)
    //adds the class strongText to the div with id currentstatus
 }
}
```

Basically I have multiple paired buckets being created depending on the complexity of the task. The third item on the class list is always the pair#. I want to be able to put it in the $([variable pair# goes here]).find("div") so I can check those pairs on the drop event. I don't know why I cannot make it work. I looked around and could not find anything. I am a new student, so maybe I am missing something over my head. I am hoping you can help.

Comment: It is really confusing what you want to do ? can you please explain sort so i can help you

Comment: Check this $("."+currentPair).find("div") or $('div[class="'+currentPair+'"]').find("div"), is this ``$(this)[0]`` a div element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that `$(this)[0].classList[3]` returns the string `'pair0'` - noting that the quotation marks are *not* part of the string - to use it as a class selector you need to add a `'.'` to the beginning, to get the string `'.pair0'`. So:

```
var currentPair = '.' + $(this)[0].classList[3]
var pairDivs = $(currentPair).find("div")
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/a6h9ru92/

---

As for why your attempts didn't work:

```
var currentPair = $(this)[0].classList[3]
var pairDivs = currentPair.find("div")
//errors: currentPair.find is not a function
```

In the above case, `currentPair` is just a string, and strings don't have a `.find()` function.

```
var pairDivs2 = $(currentPair).find("div")
//errors: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ".pair0"
```

In the `pairDivs2` case the error quoted doesn't make sense, because your code did *not* add a `'.'` to the string. I think you must have mixed up the error message with the next one.

```
var currentPair2 = '\".' + $(this)[0].classList[3] + '\"'
// my attempt to make it the string ".pair0"
console.log(currentPair2)
// logs ".pair0"
var pairDivs3 = $(currentPair2).find("div")
//errors: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ".pair0"
```

In the `pairDivs3` case, you are actually appending quotation marks into your string, so the "unrecognized expression" is because you are generating the string `'".pair0"'` (where the *single* quotes are not part of the string value, but the *double* quotes are).

---

As an aside, using `.classList[3]` is a pretty fragile way to work, because obviously that will break if the class you care about isn't exactly the fourth one one returned by `.classList`. It would probably be a lot better to use `data-` attributes, say `data-pair="1"` instead of `class="pair1"`. You can select by that attribute with `$('[data-pair="1"]')`, so:

```
var currentPair = $(this).attr('data-pair')
var pairDivs = $('[data-pair="' + currentPair + '"]').find("div")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. After poking around MDN a bit I was able to figure out how to set the data-pair dynamically. I think you may have saved me a ton of future frustration now that I know this is a thing you can do.